# When using .format for psycopg2 it reads it as a column name but no issue using %

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

when using python 3's .format with psycopg2

```
WHERE 
            US.UserId = UP.UserId AND
            UP.country = {2} 
            AND UP.state= {3} 
            AND UP.city= {4}
```

it complains that the column 'RSA' in UP.country for example does not exist. If I use %s instead as in python 2 I don’t get the same issue and it doesn’t read it as a column.

What am I missing here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%s` for variable placeholders with psycopg2.

Make sure that you are passing parameters correctly, so that they are escaped properly.

```
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar",)) # correct
```

If you use % formatting or `format()` with user input, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)" % "bar", ()) # wrong
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES ({} )".format("bar"), ()) # wrong
```

See the docs on [passing parameters to SQL queries](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for more information.

Note that `%s` formatting is supported for regular strings in Python 3, as well as `format()`

Answer (score 0):

I am note sure of the inner workings but place '{}' around resolved this issue for me.